# R IF statement with different selection

Tags: r, if-statement, logic

Ciao,

I have taken much feedback to create a reproducible example and my coding attempts.

Here is a sample data frame:

```
df <- data.frame("STUDENT" = 1:10, 
                 "test_FALL" = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, NA), 
                 "test_SPRING" = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), 
                 "score_FALL" = c(53, 52, 98, 54, 57 ,87, 62, 95, 75, NA), 
                 "score_SPRING" = c(75, 54, 57, 51, 51, 81, 77, 87, 73, 69), 
                 "final_SCORE" = c(75, 54, 57, 51, 57, 87, 62, 87, 73, 69))
```

And sample code:

```
df$final_score[df$test_SPRING  == 1] <- df$score_SPRING
df$final_score[df$test_FALL == 1] <- df$score_FALL
```

And a second attempt at the code:

```
df$final_score1[(df$test_SPRING  == 1 & !is.na(df$test_SPRING))] <- df$score_SPRING
df$final_score1[(df$test_FALL == 1 & !is.na(df$test_FALL))] <- df$score_FALL
```

In my dataframe I have when a student took a test (test_SPRING test_FALL) and scores on tests (score_SPRING score_FALL). Basically I want to create the final_SCORE column which I include in the dataframe SUCH THAT if test_SPRING = 1, tot_score = score_SPRING else if test_FALL = 1, tot_score = score_Fall. I am unable to do so and cannot figure it out after many hours. Please offer any advice you may have.

Comment: It is not clear whether you need to create `tot_score` or `final_score`  do you need `with(df, ifelse(test_SPRING == 1, score_SPRING, score_FALL))`

Comment: df %>% mutate(tot_score = ifelse(test_SPRING, score_SPRING,score_FALL))

Comment: Or use `with(df, rowSums(cbind(score_SPRING * test_SPRING,  score_FALL * test_FALL), na.rm = TRUE))`

Comment: I have edited the question to hopefully clarify it. I included final_SCORE in the dataset. That is the variable I am trying to create using final_score and final_score1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of ways to create the 'final_score'.

**1)** Using `ifelse` - Based on the example, the 'test' columns are mutually exclusive.  So, we can use a single `ifelse` by checking the condition based on 'test_SPRING' (`test_SPRING == 1`).  If it is TRUE, then get the 'score_SPRING' or else get 'score_FALSE'

```
with(df, ifelse(test_SPRING == 1, score_SPRING, score_FALL))
#[1] 75 54 57 51 57 87 62 87 73 69
```

**2)** Arithmetic - Number multiplied by 1 is the number itself and 0 gives 0 so multiply the 'score' columns with the corresponding 'test' columns, `cbind` and use `rowSums`

```
with(df,  NA^(!test_FALL & !test_SPRING) * rowSums(cbind(
                       score_SPRING * test_SPRING,  
                       score_FALL * test_FALL), 
                    na.rm = TRUE))
#[1] 75 54 57 51 57 87 62 87 73 69
```

Comment: When I do na.rm=TRUE then it gives me '0' when I am missing values in both columns. How do I set it so that I get the same result with na.rm=TRUE but instead of '0' for both missing I generate NA

Comment: @bvowe Updated the post

Comment: this is really good thank you. I am now wondering why didn't the if statement I tried work?

Comment: @bvowe `if/else` is not vectorized i.e. it works only for a single element or else you need to loop (with `for` or `lapply`) which is performance wise inefficient compared to vectorized `ifelse`

Comment: so could I do something like:

df$final_score <- ifelse(test_SPRING ==1 {score_spring} elseif test_FALL == 1 {score_fall})

Comment: @bvowe  The nested syntax for `ifelse` would be `with(df, ifeelse(test_SPRING == 1, score_spring, ifelse(test_FALL == 1, score_fall, NA)))`